# Problems with animating, translate and scale doesnt work with position absolute

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

I have a popup in my main view, it could be just a product or a list of products. In the first case the position of the popup is in some point of the view (top and left, i already have a method for that) and it has a zoom animation. But if it is a list the position is at the right and the animation a slide.

In the view:

```
<div data-ng-if="showProduct" id="product" data-ng-class="animation">
  <div class="productContainer" data-ng-style="productStyle()">
    <div class="productContent">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span data-ng-if="isProductList" class="closeIcon" data-ng-click="close()"></span>
</div>
```

In the controller: (this is for showing the idea, of course it is not like this)

```
$scope.productStyle = function () {
    return { top: "0", left: "auto", right: "0", height: "100%" };
}

$scope.animation = true==true ? "slideAnimation" : "zoomAnimation";

$scope.close = function () {
    $scope.showProduct = false;
}
```

The sass:

```
#main {
  position:relative;  
}

@mixin transform($value) {
    transform: $value;
    -ms-transform: $value;
    -webkit-transform: $value;
}

@mixin transitionDuration ($duration) {
    transition-duration: $duration;
    -webkit-transition-duration: $duration;
}

#product {
  position:static;

    .productContainer {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:3;
        overflow-y:auto;
        width: 32%;
        background-color: green;

        .productoContent {
          width: 200px;
          height:200px;
        }
    }

    .closeIcon {     
        position: absolute;
        width: 5%;
        height: 54px;
        background: #333;
        z-index: 3;
        top: -20px;
        left: 63%;
        padding-left: 2%;
        padding-top: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }                 
}

.zoomAnimation {

    &.ng-enter {
        @include transitionDuration(250ms);
        @include transform(scale(1.3));
        opacity: 0;
    }

    &.ng-enter-active {
      @include transform(scale(1));
        opacity: 1; 
    }

    &.ng-leave {
      @include transitionDuration(250ms);
      @include transform(scale(1));
          opacity: 1;
    }

    &.ng-leave-active {
        @include transform(scale(1.5));
        opacity: 0; 
    }
}

.slideAnimation {

    &.ng-enter {
        @include transform(translateX(200%));
        @include transitionDuration(250ms);
        opacity: 0; 
    }

    &.ng-enter-active {
        @include transform(translateX(0));
        opacity: 1; 
    }

    &.ng-leave {
        @include transform(translateX(0));
        @include transitionDuration(1.5s);
        opacity: 1; 
    }

    &.ng-leave-active {
        @include transform(translateX(200%));
        opacity: 0; 
    }
}
```

I can not remove the absolute position because everything else is broken, but if i remove it scale and translate works. Someone has an idea for this problem?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: first, you are placing an absoluted position element (.productContainer) inside a parent with static position (#product)...you are taking a HUGE risk of css bubbling. second, **can not remove the absolute position because everything else is broken** - what exactly happening when you set position to relative? how it effects the position of this element?

Comment: thanks for your answe, in case of #product with position:relative goes to the bottom and with absolute dissapears. Now, with .productContainer is the same but with relative dissapears and without absolute and relative goes to the bottom

Comment: wow... any chance to re-produce this behavior with jdFiddle?

Comment: Finally i solved it, i have changed the static position in #main to relative and #product in absolute. Also, the ng-styles are in the #product tag now. Thanks for the static information !